# Añadir clase "active" según la url - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

Buenas noches quiero añadir una clase según en la url que estoy, utilizo laravel y normalmente utilizo algo como esto:

> @if(request()->segment(1) === 'nuestra-carta') active_blanco @endif

```
<li>
  <a href="{{ route('web.carta') }}" class="@if(request()->segment(1) === 'nuestra-carta') active_blanco @endif" title="Nuestra carta">Nuestra carta</a>
</li>
```

Pero cuando estoy en la home, no segment.

¿Hay alguna posibilidad de detectar que estoy en la home?

Comment: No estoy si segment debiera devolverte `/` o una cadena vacía cuando estás en el _home_, ¿has intentado validar eso?

Comment: No es lo que estás preguntando, pero lo que haría es ponerle nombre a las rutas de laravel, entonces luego puedo obtenerlo para hacer la comparación. Por ejemplo `request()->route()->getName() === 'home'`

Comment: Si, eso lo se @porloscerrosΨ , pero por saber si podia hacerlo sin necesidad de poner `'home` ya que no me gusta la url así

Comment: Hola @jachguate he probado a dejarlo vacio, añadirle un `/` pero sin éxito

Comment: Me refería al nombre de la ruta, la url podría ser cualquiera, incluso sólo la barra `/` https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: Ah! No te había entendido, voy a probarlo, gracias!

Comment: Funciona perfecto @porloscerrosΨ , podrías publicar una respuesta por si le sirve a alguien, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es lo que estás preguntando, de hacerlo analizando la url.
Pero lo que haría es ponerle nombre a las rutas de laravel, entonces luego podría obtener la ruta del request actual `request()->route()` y de la ruta obtener el nombre `route()->getName()`.
Por ejemplo:

A la ruta que corresponde a la url base, o sea sólo la barra `/`, le pongo de nombre `home`:

```php
Route::get(
    '/',
    [HomeController::class, 'index']
)->name('home'); // <- esto
```

***Nota**: cada nombre de ruta debe ser único en la aplicación.*

Luego, obtengo la ruta correspondiente al request actual, y de ella el nombre

```php
$route_name = request()->route()->getName(); 
// si la url del request actual es /, $route_name va a valer "home"
```

Y para tu caso, hacer un condicional en una vista, sería algo así:

```php
class="@if(request()->route()->getName() === 'home') active_blanco @endif"
```

Fuentes:
Doc. Laravel Routing [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes).
Api Laravel `Illuminate\Routing\Route` [método getName()](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getName)